# Should I mark an answer that doesn't actually solve the issue (turned out impossible), but has the best debugging info?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions

I have a dilemma:

I have [two](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/352/save-issue-submitting-entry-edits-redirects-to-control-panel-top) [questions](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/959/file-modal-doesnt-act-on-any-search-filtering) that [Tom](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/104/tom-davies) did a heroic job of trying to answer, including some really useful steps for debugging the issue in a standard case where this kind of issue arose.  Unfortunately, due to circumstances I hadn't laid out in my question, it turned out that it wasn't possible for this to get a correct answer.  It wasn't really possible for me to provide enough detail either.

What my gut tells me to do is edit my original questions and explain that the cause of the issue ended up being some security fix code given to me by ellislab that seems to have introduced other issues, that the solution for me pending getting that code fixed was to toggle a setting in the control panel, and to mark Tom's answers as correct.  Would this be the right course of action or should the question be deleted, or something else?

Comment: I think marking it as accepted is fine. At least he gets +25 rep for "heroic effort".

Comment: Good enough for me, I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I guess, since Adrian's comment was the only one, and that no one disagreed, this will suffice for consensus for the time being.  It seems like even if your question went off the rails for some reason out of the control of the community here and couldn't be answered, the best policy is to select the answer containing the most useful information towards solving your issue or a similar issue under less strange circumstances.

Comment: I haven't read the particular question, but maybe in hindsight it wasn't a good fit for SE anyway if it turned out impossible to answer? Regardless, I think everyone should aim to accept 100% of questions they ask (even if they post and accept their own answer), so in this case I think you made the right choice. Interested to hear if anyone else has opinions on this though.

Comment: I think it was fine for StackExchange, it just turned out to be based on some unreleased code from EllisLab that had a bug in it.  It didn't seem likely to me that that was the cause when I posted.